# setEnvIf and RewriteCond doesn't catch it

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, setenvif

I'm setting this in my vhost in Apache 2.4

```
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on
```

And in my .htaccess I add this rule :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

but I get an infinit loop since my RewriteCond doesn't see the value of HTTPS.

I do a `phpinfo(INFO_VARIABLES);` and I get `$_SERVER['HTTPS']  on`

I had debug in my errorLog to get this `RewriteCond: input='off' pattern='off' => matched`
As you see the RewriteCond doesn't see the value I set.

I read some doc as

> The SetEnv directive runs late during request processing meaning that
>   directives such as SetEnvIf and RewriteCond will not see the variables
>   set with it.

or this link : http://www.onlinesmartketer.com/2010/05/27/apache-environment-variables-visibility-with-setenv-setenvif-and-rewriterule-directives/#Summary

And what I did is supposed to work.

What's wrong ? 
Thanks ;)

Comment: Use the mod_rewrite functional. `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !^https`

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the .htaccess since it's commun to all different environment. I can't only update my vhost.

Comment: Try E-flag. `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} https`\n`RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTPS:on]`

Comment: I tried your command line and it doesn't work. I even just add     RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTPS:on] and with the  phpinfo(INFO_VARIABLES); I don't see this variable :  $_SERVER['HTTPS']

Comment: I also try this exemple : https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html

And it doesn't work in my php I can't see the new variable.

Comment: yes, in fact we get `%{ENV:HTTPS}` that is not the same as `%{HTTPS}`. Maybe due to security reasons.